# in python OOP How to print a list of objects with attributes and add the total of the price of each product

Tags: python, oop

I'm a really begginer with python and OOP, I want to print a list of 3 objects with 3 properties each, one of the properties is the price and I want that in the end these three prices add up to give me the total money that cost the 3 products.
Here's my code:

```
    from products import PhysicalProduct

class Checkout:
    def get_total(self, product_list):
        total = 0
        for product in product_list:
            total += product.price
        return total

        def print_list(self, product_list):
            #print products with sku, price and the total

            pass


checkout = Checkout()
product_list = [
    #The properties are: "name", "sku", price
    PhysicalProduct("television", "100", 100),
    PhysicalProduct("radio", "101", 80),
    PhysicalProduct("computer", "105", 1080),
]
print(checkout.get_total(product_list))
```

**It should look something like this:**
television: sku: 100 price: 100
radio: sku: 101 price: 80
computer: sku: 105 price 1080
total: 1260

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: show how should look the final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following `print_list` method declaration:

```
def print_list(self, product_list):
    for product in product_list:
        print(product.name, 'sku: {:0} price: {:1}'.format(product.sku, product.price))
    print('total:', self.get_total(product_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be hard.  You may not even need that second function in there but, if you want to have it, then you could do something like this:

```
class Checkout:
    def get_total(self, product_list):
        total = 0
        for product in product_list:
            total += product.price
        return total

    def print_list(self, product_list, total):
        #print products with sku, price and the total
        for item in product_list:
            print(item.name + ": sku: " + item.sku + " price: " + str(item.price), end="")
        print()
        print("total: " + str(total))

checkout = Checkout()
product_list = [
    #The properties are: "name", "sku", price
    PhysicalProduct("television", "100", 100),
    PhysicalProduct("radio", "101", 80),
    PhysicalProduct("computer", "105", 1080),
]
total = checkout.get_total(product_list)
checkout.print_list(product_list, total)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for product in product_list:
    print(product.name +': sku: '+product.sku+' price: '+product.price)
print('total: ' + str(checkout.get_total(product_list)))
```

this should do the requested